# Why is $\overrightarrow{OM}$ in that form?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

We have the following:

[image]

We have that $M$ is on the line segment $AB$.

$\overrightarrow{OA}=\overrightarrow{a}$

$\overrightarrow{OB}=\overrightarrow{b}$

Could you explain to me why it stands that $$\overrightarrow{OM}=s \overrightarrow{a}+(1-s)\overrightarrow{b}, 0 \leq s \leq 1$$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Write $\overrightarrow{OM} = \overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{AM} = \vec a + \dots$.

Comment: Do we use the parametric equation of the line that passes through $A$ and $B$ ??

Comment: Well, if you knew that, @MaryStar, you'd be done to start with :) What does it say about the vector $\overrightarrow{AM}$ if we know $M$ lies on $\overline{AB}$?

Comment: That it is of the form: $$\overrightarrow{AM}=s\overrightarrow{AB}, 0\leq s \leq 1$$ right?? @TedShifrin

Comment: @MaryStar, you are in good hands.

Comment: Absolutely, @MaryStar. You are good enough to have got this on your own!!

Comment: It stands that $\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{b}-\overrightarrow{a}$, so we have that $\overrightarrow{AM}=s(\overrightarrow{b}-\overrightarrow{a})$. Therefore, $$\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{a}+s(\overrightarrow{b}-\overrightarrow{a})=s\overrightarrow{b}+(1-s)\overrightarrow{a}, 0\leq s \leq 1$$ right??

Comment: To get $$\overrightarrow{OM}=s\overrightarrow{a}+(1-s)\overrightarrow{b}, 0 \leq s \leq 1$$ we would have to take $$\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{BM}$$ right?? @TedShifrin

Comment: OK, @MaryStar, you're right. I messed up. :) But, see, you can figure it out for yourself!!

Comment: Is it $$\overrightarrow{BM}=s \overrightarrow{AB}, 0\leq s \leq 1$$ or should it be "$-s$" instead of "$s$" ?? @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

In this linear-combination

$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OM}}=\lambda  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OA}}+\mu  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OB}}$

with

$\lambda +\mu =1$

one let

$\mu =1-\lambda$

which gives

$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OM}}=\lambda  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OA}}+(1-\lambda ) \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OB}}$

with

$0\leq \lambda \leq 1$

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MaryStar: I like to use these arrows, because in affinian geometry it's standart if one has given a point to start and another to end with. Called bounded direction (or vector).